# Matlab find the smallest number within variables

Tags: matlab

Say I have 10 variables which have different numbers within them(num1 = 0.4123,num2 = 0.6223,num3 etc.). How can i find the variable which has the smallest number? Do i need to use recursive loop or is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Put them in an array and use `min`.

Comment: It would be much better to have all those variables as entries of a numeric vector: `num = [0.4123 0.6223]` etc. Then you'd use `[~, result] = min(num)` to get the arg min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a bunch of numbers delineated by separate variable names is awful.  I would recommend doing what @LuisMendo suggested and place them all into an array.

However, if you don't want to punch in all of those numbers into a single array, you can cheat and save all variables that start with `num`, then load it back into MATLAB inside a struct.  Convert the struct into an array by converting it into a cell array, and then a numeric array.

Once you do that, use the `min` call that he was talking about.  In other words:

```
save('temp.mat', 'num*'); %// Save all variables with num from workspace to file
s = load('temp.mat'); %// Reload back in as a structure
vals = cell2mat(struct2cell(s)); %// Convert from structure to numeric array
[~,idx] = min(vals); %// Find value that was the minimum
f = fieldnames(s); %// Get all of the variable names
disp(f{idx}); %// Display the variable that has the minimum
```

`idx` would be the number that resulted in the minimum.   If you want to display the actual name of the variable that resulted in the minimum, you can use `fieldnames` to retrieve a list of all of the variables from the structure, then index into that with the minimum value to get the result.

Or, if you can bear the typing, just do this:

```
vals = [num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 num8 num9 num10];
[~,idx] = min(vals);
disp(['num' num2str(idx)]);
```

The first way would be preferable if you have a lot of variables that you want to find the `min` of.  If this is the case, you should consider placing all of the values in an array and reformulate your code.  Having a lot of variables declared in your code makes it unmanageable.

Comment: Good idea! Might save a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to have all those variables as entries of a numeric vector:

```
 num = [0.4123 0.6223];
```

Then you would use

```
[~, result] = min(num);
```

to get the index of the minimum element.

Comment: Plus 1 for you too :) It was your idea originally!